# Opening an undefined URL with xmlHttp Request

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I'm making a server request like this:

```
    //document.write("getmessages.php?q="+employeee);
    xmlHttp.open("GET","../ajax/getmessages.php?q="+employeee,true);

    // define the method to handle server responses
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    // make the server request
    xmlHttp.send(null);
```

The code works fine, but its trying to make a popup, which if I open it, comes up with:

```
The requested URL /undefined was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I'm not sure what's causing this error

Comment: Where is there any code about a popup here? [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), ***please.***

Comment: Is your ajax directory within an accessible folder? What happens if you got to: `../ajax/getmessages.php` directly in your browser?

Comment: getmessages is returning what I want, so it seems its working fine

Comment: Can you show us the handleServerResponse function?